22.04: Is it possible to allow any valid user to unlock the screen?
I have what may seem like a strange need: I would like to allow any valid user to unlock a screen that has been locked. Right now, only the user that actually started the X session can unlock the screen (we are using gnome, not wayland if that matters).
More information: This is a 22.04 system that will be used in a medical office. Under normal circumstances the machine will be booted up and then logged in to a well-known default user (I may actually have it auto-login). However for compliance reasons it is required that the screen must lock after a configurable inactivity time. What we need is a way to allow any valid user to then unlock the screen, and I don't want to hand out that default user/password combination.
Right now we are looking at having to home grow our own application (possibly suite of applications) to accomplish this, but it sure seems like there should be some sort of pam sort of way to make this happen without having to re-write the world!

The screen is being locked to protect others from accessing the desktop of the current user. So no, no other user will be able to access that desktop.
You can set up multiple passwords for a single account, thus have different users unlock that screen with a distinct password. However, there is no mechanism to see which password was used to unlock the screen. The account also becomes more vulnerable, because now, there are multiple passwords to access it.
So you can as well make life easy to yourself and provide the trusted users with a password that you change regularly. These are trusted users, after all.
Setting up multiple passwords for a single account is not standard, but can be done using additional tools. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90684/can-you-give-a-user-account-multiple-passwords for initial hints.

I realize that what you describe is the standard answer, however in my case I actually want to have many users that have access to the system without having to logout the auto-logged in user. In our application the system is really a medical device that just happens to run on a Linux system. The application that is running needs to keep running when the screen is locked, but some other user may need to be able to unlock the screen in order to access the application.
What I'm wondering is if I can somehow plug my own authentication scheme into whatever gdm is using for authentication.

Give them the same password. Security wise, it is better than setting up different passwords. You may consider this a "standard answer", but I indicated you can set up multiple passwords, but it becomes more complicated with dedicated tools. If it is like this, then that is the only way I can answer. I think an answer you may not like but that reflects the situation is better than no answer at all.
